# Keyloggers for Windows 7 (and how does McAfee find malware)?

Tags: windows-7, anti-virus, keylogger

I would like to install a keyboard sniffer (AKA keylogger) on Windows 7 64-bit.
However, when I go to most of these sites I get a warning from McAfee. And
probably if I install the software McAfee will find it and report it as
malware.

1. Are there any keyloggers compatible with McAfee?
2. How does McAfee web browser plugin manage to report the software download web page
   (does it keep a database of dangerous sites somewhere on the network and check this way,
   and if so, is this list maintained by humans)?
3. How would McAfee intercept the keylogger? Would it, say, compute the hash of the
   binary code for the program and compare the computed hash against a database on
   the network?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Any software is compatible with any antivirus as long as you can put the program on the "[Exclude list](http://download.mcafee.com/products/webhelp/5/1033/index.html#GUID-7A7B8997-88DB-46C3-9A64-1240B3A98E6A.html)". That will make the virus scan skip the program when checking for virus signatures.
2. It does exactly like you guessed, it keeps a database of dangerous sites. However it does not check the network it keeps a local copy of the database on your computer. That database is updated every time you do a "[Check for updates](http://download.mcafee.com/products/webhelp/5/1033/GUID-211B61CF-D556-4797-BB8B-74386B84516F.html)". You must [have a subscription](http://download.mcafee.com/products/webhelp/5/1033/GUID-67CC80F4-2F10-4E27-B9A6-06EA36F1D46B.html) to get new updates. How that list is maintained is not publicly disclosed by McAfee to my knowledge.
3. Very similar to how you guessed, it has "Signatures" which are like hashes of parts of binary code. If the binary it is checking contains the "Signature" it will flag it as a virus. The list of signatures are stored locally on your computer and updated when you do a check for updates just as in question 2.

Answer (score 1):

McAfee SiteAdvisor isn't reliable at all. I tried that thing about 6 months ago, it was acting weird.

I'm using a program called Spytector ( http://www.spytector.com ) since the beginning of the year and it runs undetected. McAfee could warn you when you visit Spytector website, but their keylogger won't be stopped by the antivirus.

Comment: Now that is an excellent program. Thanks for pointing it out! :-) (too bad it's a bit pricey though)